# toggle() hide/show with different element

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I got a list table, so when I click one of list table on it, another list show. and i click back, list will be hide. here is the code for the hide and show.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Hide table rows with class 'min', but appear when clicked.
  $(".data").hide();
  $(".main").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().next(".data").toggle();
  });

});
```

but, when i click back.  can't hide.
Please correct me.
Thanks

[Check my example](http://jsfiddle.net/wG8qf/346/)

Comment: use different class name for back button and a new function.

Comment: its impossible use one function with toggle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wG8qf/356/)**

If the `.main` clicked has a parent with class `.data`, then it means click was on a new shown row. So we find the parent div and close it.
Else we will find and hide/show the immediate next row.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Hide table rows with class 'min', but appear when clicked.
    $(".data").hide();
    $(".main").click(function () {
        if($(this).parents('.data').length)
            $(this).closest('.data').toggle();
        else
            $(this).next(".data").toggle();
    });
});
```